# Where to find the Record type listed in Current Data Storage Usage?

Tags: data-storage

I tried to understand the Record Type in the "Current Data Storage Usage" list view. I took that names of the below record types and searched in Account object to see if there are any record types in that name exists. I didn't find a one. Second, I don't know what is Message Logs, etc. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Account Sales Summary By Year
Message Logs
Product Unit of Measure Conversions

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nomenclature is a bit confusing, considering we have a feature called [Record Types](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/projects/customize-a-salesforce-object/create-record-types), but Storage Usage does not refer to *that* feature. It's the type of the record involved, commonly called an sObject type. You have objects called "Account Sales Summary By Year", "Message Logs", etc. These appear to be custom objects. Each custom object record consumes 2KB of space (500 per MB, 500,000 per GB); some standard objects [have different space requirements](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318951&type=1&mode=1). These types are directly found in Object Manager in Lightning Setup, and under Setup > Create > Objects in Classic Setup.

Comment: As you said, it is so much confusing as I tried to find the storage for Product2 but I didn't find but what I saw is Product References. Then, I compared the record count and it seems to be equal and same. Thanks for clarifying as your answer will be very helpful to everyone.

Comment: @Bforce Product records themselves don't use storage, so they don't appear in the list, unless you have Long Text Area/Rich Text Area fields, which can use storage.